# select from a list of disks

Tags: graphics, filtering

I have the following list of centers of disks.

```
r=0.03;
pts = {{0.10420089319018544`, -0.024872674177014872`}, \
{0.9743669105930046`, 0.9169054125547074`}, {0.028760526736240563`, 
    0.45959879163736717`}, {-0.0059035632830851115`, 
    0.2922099255180086`}, {0.41615337459441437`, 
    0.9928402345083696`}, {0.23798002911834915`, 
    0.028922198016334083`}, {0.9439796979256947`, 
    0.014706790894535735`}, {1.0038820168274474`, 
    0.677501854561434`}, {0.5927003061040934`, 
    1.0077273741847754`}, {1.0067437297432018`, 
    0.9752013154551493`}, {0.6938266053169369`, 
    1.0266240439258578`}, {0.98338794538608`, 
    0.26086568952319356`}, {0.9782652227588948`, 
    0.5171196676396621`}, {0.2545283903372031`, 
    1.0169130378365447`}, {-0.004475792541620699`, 
    0.08252251782338371`}, {0.0792067543327557`, 
    1.0190929886159708`}, {0.01012007453604613`, 
    0.9742793220312869`}, {0.37795635641517067`, 
    0.0006807388703829187`}, {0.16475658437291774`, 
    1.0073414058455288`}, {0.7109091765268767`, 
    0.010031721670787197`}, {0.751636715216994`, 
    0.9718377389063747`}, {-0.02868599270782108`, 
    0.8001977126969162`}, {0.9951076171959166`, 
    0.06361811727917832`}, {0.48856448143911413`, 
    0.9822360639397044`}, {0.8498119226349552`, 
    0.9954192191276157`}, {0.9343505459643862`, 
    1.026090808866221`}, {-0.02352512434168942`, 
    0.3638162649853829`}, {0.015464116868890446`, 
    0.8880954853506882`}, {0.5397449644933747`, 
    0.0075650003442971625`}, {1.0124037284145468`, 
    0.3445056232122783`}, {0.012611151682823951`, 
    0.22876062170703393`}, {0.01349201390129795`, 
    0.012484449700555664`}, {1.0287174186840569`, 
    0.4444472847751937`}, {1.0148117241333423`, 
    0.8423869907442485`}, {0.028166977268371904`, 
    0.749683634621167`}, {0.17535597671574954`, \
-0.02307375065511537`}, {0.6373054881521303`, -0.02231729523620847`}, \
{0.9791564983854446`, 0.7765347566257843`}, {-0.028389156500012468`, 
    0.7133375307394074`}, {0.47391260398278434`, \
-0.0029577636868491908`}, {0.009099484184960496`, 
    0.5770732674239099`}, {1.013402544772932`, 
    0.17610957824632423`}, {0.9714646177489623`, 
    0.6166237906203449`}, {0.30769518373972393`, \
-0.008573400690361568`}, {0.8261937637371302`, 
    0.001386073976981178`}, {0.8914586354858451`, \
-0.026330731282082395`}, {0.02725861951844763`, 
    0.6605283794945094`}, {-0.026575383043093995`, 
    0.5203231079582309`}, {0.004468178226517766`, 
    0.16296092728164324`}, {0.3189756417708023`, 0.9723496550714829`}};

Graphics[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.8], 
  EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Black}], Disk[#, r] & /@ pts}, 
 Background -> Lighter[Gray], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

I want to delete from this list the centers that are above the line in the figure below

[image]

I use

```
ptsxy = DeleteCases[
   pts, {x_, 
     y_} /; (0.05 <= x <= 1 && y >= 0.9) || (0 <= y <= 1 && x >= 0.9)];
Graphics[{FaceForm@Lighter[Blue, 0.8], 
  EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Black}], Disk[#, r] & /@ ptsxy}, 
 Background -> Lighter[Gray], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

But I am sure that there are better ways.

Comment: What's `r`? It's not defined in the posted code.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. `r=0.03`

Comment: Also, do you have an actual equation for the line? The region you've (implicitly) defined using `DeleteCases` isn't it....

Comment: No I don't have a particular equation for the line. It's just to visualize which disks I want to get rid of. Thr line was adding with `DrawingTools` after the creation of the `Graphic`.

Comment: OK, good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use geometry property. Let's say your equation of line is `x+y-1=0`. You can distinguish whether a point lies on same side as that of the origin by substituting the points into the equation of line. If the value is same that when origin `0,0` is substituted, then the point lies on the same side.

Here is a simple code that you can use:

```
eqline = (x + y - 1);
snOrigin = Sign[(eqline /. {x -> 0, y -> 0})];
Select[pts, (eqline /. {x -> First@#,y -> Last@#})*snOrigin > 0 &];
```

This should give you all the points which lie on the side of the line containing the origin.

Comment: Nice. Actually I want the lower side but it is very. Just change your code to  `eqline = (x + y - 1);
Select[pts, (eqline /. {x -> First@#,y -> Last@#})*(eqline /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}) > 0 &];` Thanks!

Comment: Also, you can use some other point as reference, if you are not very fond of origin!

Answer (score 2):

Given the definition of the circle centres in `pts`, and a line parameterised by `y=m*x+b`.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{r = 0.03, x = pts[[All, 1]], y = pts[[All, 2]], p},
      p = Pick[pts, UnitStep[y - m*x - b], 0];
      Graphics[{
         EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.004], Black}], FaceForm[Lighter[Blue, 0.8]],
         Map[Disk[#, r] &, p],
         Thin, Map[Circle[#, r] &, pts],
         Red, Line[Select[Transpose[{x, m*x + b}], -0.4 < #[[2]] < 1.4 &]]
         }, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}, Frame -> True]],
  {{m, -1.0}, -10., 10., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{b, 1.0}, -5., 5., Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: delete circles]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot select all of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use `RegionMember` and `HalfPlane`. First, I reproduced your diagram, after explicitly drawing the square and tweaking the formatting a bit:

```
square = {
   FaceForm[{Lighter@Gray, Opacity[0.2]}],
   EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.002], Black}],
   Rectangle[{0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 1.0}]};

disks[pts_] := {
   EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.001], Black}],
   Disk[#, r] & /@ its};

Graphics[{
  square,
  {FaceForm[{Lighter@Blue, Opacity[0.2]}],
   disks[pts]}}]
```

[image: disks]

Then I used the drawing tools to draw a line similar to the one you provided, and assigned the edited `Graphics` object to a variable using copy and paste:

[image: illustration]

This allowed me to use cases to pick out the points defining that line, and then construct a `RegionMember` function to see which centers were in the `HalfPlane` above it:

```
With[{hp = FirstCase[pic, Line[ps_] :> HalfPlane[ps, {0, 1}], 
    Missing["NotFound"], Infinity]}, With[{fn = RegionMember[hp]}, 
  With[{split = GroupBy[pts, fn]}, 
   Graphics[
    {square, 
     {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Opacity[0.2], 
      Darker[Gray], hp}, 
     {FaceForm[{Lighter[Green], Opacity[0.3]}], 
      disks[split[False]]}, 
     {FaceForm[{Lighter[Red], Opacity[0.3]}], 
      disks[split[True]]}}]]]]
```

Here, I used `GroupBy` to allow me to separate members from non-members in one swell foop. I also drew the `HalfPlane`, and drew the rejected disks in red instead of just omitting them.

[image]